# Element not interacatable and not reachable by keyboard error By Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

At the time of texting 'hello' to someone, when I send `keys`, it shows:

> exception'ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  is not reachable by keyboard'.

This is the code I used:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys

browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.messenger.com/')
user=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#email')
user.send_keys('ctg@gmail.com')
password=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#pass')
password.send_keys('abc')
sign=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginbutton')
sign.click()  
n=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#row_header_id_user\:100002054664349 > a:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)')
n.click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('._1mf').send_keys('hello')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PYTHON PROJECT/mesg.py", line 16, in 
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('._1mf').send_keys('hi')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  is not reachable by keyboard.

Can anyone tell me where's the problem?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and the error stack trace.

Comment: Seems it's not complete code according to your Traceback.

Comment: I have added the complete code.